I can't access the profil page when deployed my next js app with docker and github actions in ec2 ubuntu instance
I have an e-commerce app and i deployed it in ec2 ubuntu instance with docker hub and github actions. I'm exposing my app in port 3000 and i created a 3000 port in the security group of my instance. So the url to access my app is http://ec2-3-29-107-165.me-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/.
I wanted to see if everything is ok and there are no issues but the profil page is not getting the addresses of the current user. Since there are no logs in ubuntu instance to check errors, i installed Sentry (Set it up manually) and Sentry is saying that the issue is a network error but is not showing the line responsible for that error. HELPPP ME !!!!
.env file
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://ec2-3-29-107-165.me-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://ec2-3-29-107-165.me-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000

There are other variables but i will not post them here.
Docker File:
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
     if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
     elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
     elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
     else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
     fi


FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT=3000

ENV HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0"
CMD ["node", "server.js"]


why dont you serve you application with nginx reverse proxy  just by proxy passing your next.js in nginx.config. you just need to enable http and https port i.e 80 and 443 in secuirty group. its pretty easy to serve you conatiner app with nginx. i can  help you setup if you want

@0xn0b174 i'm using caddy but i wanted to make sure that everything is working before enabling https. Does enabling https is the solution to the issue ?

if you are using caddy then you dont need to expose 3000 in SG just proxy pass your app to  port 80 and check in  the ip of ec2
